# Updating javascript files reflects in client-pc but not changed in server-pc

Tags: javascript, server, xampp

I have installed XAMPP Server in my pc and built a webdocument editor using javascript. So, other people connected with the same Local Area Network could access the editor using my ip address (10.11.201.93:81).

Now i have been frequently changing some javascript files from my pc but surprisingly the changes are not reflected in my pc whereas from other client pc, I could notice the changes.

For Example- Here's a portion of change of a file named table.js

```
contents: [ {
            id: 'info',
            label: editor.lang.table.title,
            elements: [ {
                type: 'hbox',
                widths: [ null, null ],
                styles: [ 'vertical-align:top' ],
                children: [ {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    padding: 0,
                    children: [ {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'txtRows',
                        'default': 5, // **Number of rows in the table**
                        label: editor.lang.table.rows,
                        required: true,
                        controlStyle: 'width:5em',
                        validate: validatorNum( editor.lang.table.invalidRows ),
                        setup: function( selectedElement ) {
                            this.setValue( selectedElement.$.rows.length );
                        },
                        commit: commitValue
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'txtCols',
                        'default': 5, // **Number of columns in the table**
                        label: editor.lang.table.columns,
                        required: true,
                        controlStyle: 'width:5em',
                        validate: validatorNum( editor.lang.table.invalidCols ),
                        setup: function( selectedTable ) {
                            this.setValue( tableColumns( selectedTable ) );
                        },
                        commit: commitValue
                    },
```

Here I just changed the # of rows and columns for the table to **5,5**, from **3,2** respectively using `default` in the code above.

And the result in my server pc, changes do not affect as showing 3 and 2

[image]

But in the client pc changes are reflected... showing 5 and 5

[image]

Comment: have you tried to clear your browser cache?

Comment: Yes....  clearing the cache works perfectly. So, i have to clear the browser cache every time i made any change of my source codes ??

Comment: not always, but to make sure it is cleared, you can work in private mode

Comment: Thaks... so silly question though ... should I delete this question ??

Comment: Why? leave it for others to see

Answer (score 0):

Its not nothing but simple a cache clear problem